# css button active state causing text to move?

Tags: css, html, firefox, cross-browser

I'm just working on some rough examples for a new site i'm working on.

for some reason the later 2 of these buttons in firefox(latest) will move the text slightly as if implementing a click animation as they enter the active state. why would the first button not also be experiencing this issue?

code below

```
<fieldset style="width:320px; float:left;">
        <legend>Pink Button</legend>
            <button class="pinkbutton"><span>MESSAGE HERE</span></button>
            <button class="pinkbuttondisabled" disabled="disabled"><span>DISABLED</span></button>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="width:320px; float:left;">
        <legend>Grey Button</legend>
            <button class="greybutton"><span>MESSAGE HERE</span></button>
            <button class="greybuttondisabled" disabled="disabled"><span>DISABLED</span></button>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="width:320px; float:left;">
        <legend>White Button</legend>
            <button class="whitebutton"><span>MESSAGE HERE</span></button>
            <button class="whitebuttondisabled" disabled="disabled"><span>DISABLED</span></button>

    </fieldset>
```

css below

```
.pinkbutton { border:1px solid #D2247b; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#EF0093; color:#FFF;}
.pinkbutton:hover {border:1px solid #FF4296; background-color:#FF5EAC;}
.pinkbutton:active {border:1px solid #A61D61; background-color:#DC2F85; color:#333232;}
.pinkbuttondisabled {border:1px solid #F3C4DB; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#FDC6E2; color:#FFF;}


.greybutton { border:1px solid #BBBBBB; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#E2E2E2; color:#8d8c8c;}
.greybutton:hover {border:1px solid #EF0093; background-color:#E2E2E2; color:#f62c92;}
.greybutton:active {border:1px solid #696969; background-color:#BFBFBF; color:#424242;}
.greybuttondisabled {border:1px solid #D5D4D4; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#F4F4F4; color:#d5d4d4;}

.whitebutton { border:1px solid #EF0093; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#FFF; color:#EF0093;}
.whitebutton:hover {border:1px solid #898989; background-color:#FFF; color:#898989;}
.whitebutton:active {border:1px solid #898989; background-color:#E2E2E2; color:#979696;}
.whitebuttondisabled {border:1px solid #FAB2DE; width:150px; height:30px; background-color:#FFF; color:#FAB2DE;}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Appears there's some padding on the :active state. I added 'padding: 0;' to the initial css declarations (so that it's inherited regardless of state) and it fixed the issue.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxx4V/).

I don't know why it happened on only the last 2 buttons though.

Answer (score 0):

James Healey solution works great. http://jsfiddle.net/pxx4V/
I just wanted to clarify the three buttons had the same problem, it was just a "visual effect" that make them seem they didn't. Here is a Fiddle with the problem, where I just changed the text color of the .pinkbutton:active to #FFF http://jsfiddle.net/6L6yu/