# How to prevent button text movement when button is active in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Sample:

```
<button>Button</button>


button {
    border: medium none;
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 224px;
    height: 40px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #7BA6BB;
    color: #FFF;
    outline: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByaLZN

Browser: Mozilla Firefox (the latest version)

When button is clicked (active), button text moves right. How To prevent it?

Comment: You might as well watch your language. It's a Q&A site here, not your every day rage forum.

Comment: Bram Yanroy, Yes, it is Q&A site here, not discussion forum to discuss about my questions frequency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css button active state causing text to move?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931038/css-button-active-state-causing-text-to-move)

Comment: Adding `padding: 0;` fixes the issue as indicated in the duplicate

Comment: Bram Yanroy, phrase "You might as well watch your language." is nation discrimination. This site is accesible for all people.

Comment: Tanner, yes, it is. But I think that target duplicate question includes the huge number of useless code and this question is better to understand ho wo solve the problem. May be exists possibility to mark target question as duplicate of my?

Comment: @user3775292 it's exactly the same problem, regardless of the amount of code. The answer is short and solves your problem, so your question is still a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: @AlexAstanin Don't be silly. I wasn't talking about your ability to speak English but about your use of "shit", which isn't that bad in its essence. But if everyone would just start using any flame and rage word that popped into his or her mind, we would have to put more time into dissecting the question and finding the core than actually answering it. Posing a question as objectively and comprehensively as possible should be anyone's priority. (I am not a native English speaker myself and would never judge someone's ability to speak English. I do not however like all the flaming and raging.)

Comment: Bram Yanroy, 1) I write this word because English is not my native language and I didn't know how to write russian folklore phrase that haven't analogue in English. It is the once analogue that I found. 2) I delete this phrase when I understood that it isn't good phrase to describe this thing.

Comment: Then I was right to point out that it isn't a good word to use on this website. So now you know and we can all live happily ever after.

Comment: Bram Yanroy, ahah, ok :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As one of solutions : add `padding:0` for `button:active`

```css
button {
  border: medium none;
  margin-top: 17px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #7BA6BB;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: medium none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Or you can add `span`(or maybe another tag that you like) into your `button` like this here:

```css
button {
  border: medium none;
  margin-top: 17px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #7BA6BB;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: medium none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If text is moving right - move button left, so text will remain in his position:

http://jsfiddle.net/goc68jy4/2/

```
button {
  ...
  padding:0px;
}
button:active{
    margin-left:-2px;
    padding-left:4px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add reset css

```
    *{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/dzxdbawv/)

Comment: Your answer suggests removing margin and padding on all elements that might appear on a page, rather than a specific targeted element.